# vs code encoding conflict between Output and matplotlib for french accents

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code, character-encoding, mojibake

when I prefix my .py file using utf-8 or Latin-1 I always get bad charcacters in OUTPUT or  in matplotlib figure text.

Post 'Working with UTF-8 encoding in Python source' does not answer my question which is specific to vs code.

In:

```
`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`
print('à')
```

Out:

```
�
```

matplotlib text with utf-8 encoding right display >
[image: matplotlib text with utf-8 encoding right display]

In:

```
`# -*- coding: Latin-1 -*-`
print('à')
```

Out:

```
à
```

matplotlib text with Latin-1 wrong display >
[image: matplotlib text with Latin-1 wrong display]

I tried different encodings but I never get proper outputs

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case: `'Périodes'.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'latin1')` returns `'PÃ©riodes'`. Switch to [UTF-8 Everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/)…

Comment: maybe your system or editor use `latin1`  and you have `latin-1` in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In vs code, I've checked Preferences > Settings > code runner : Run in Terminal so I no longer need to use the utf-8 code substitute in the plain text, I can now write "à" or any accentuated letter directly so OUTPUT and matplotlib are OK.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you JosefZ.

I adopt UTF-8 everywhere.

`print('\xc3\xa0')` fixed the issue.

`print('à'.encode('utf-8'))` to find the code.

I you have better solution configuring matplotlib avoiding to use codes,  I'll take it.

Comment: `print('à')` should work fine if your editor is really using UTF-8.